# Conditional require based on select value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

My user must select home visits date (date picker) in textbox if home visit selection selected value is YES.

```
<p>Home Visit Done: 

<select name="hvdone" required>
     <option selected="selected" ><?= isset($_POST['name']) ? htmlspecialchars($hvdone) : '' ?></option>       
     <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
     <option value="No">No</option>
</select>

<p>HV date (Mandatory): <input type="text" id="datepicker" style="background-color:red; color: white;" name="hvdate" value="<?= isset($_POST['name']) ? htmlspecialchars($hvdate) : '' ?>"/></p>
```

My problem is I have already ID attribute inserted for date picker, now I have to insert one more id attribute to make sure the same textbox to be mandatory required for jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't need anyother `attribute` for that. Just use the `id` of datepicker and add required constraint to it

Comment: textbox should be required only if the selection option selected value if Yes. if user selected value No then form can save the empty value.

Comment: I have two Jquiry function, one is for date picker, one more is to make sure if home visit selection selected value is YES then the date picker text box should be required, if No then form can save the empty value.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This what you want. It's even in pure javascript

```js
function getVal(ele){
var element = document.getElementById("datepicker")
 ele.value == "yes" ? element.required =true : element.required =false
}
getVal(document.getElementById("select"))
```

```html
<form>
<select id="select" onchange="getVal(this);">
<option value="yes">Yes</option>
<option value="no">No</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="datepicker" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Glad to know that :)